# Grafana `group_by [re_replace ...` breaks text in the legend

Tags: grafana, monitoring-query-language

I'm using the following graph definition

```
fetch my_source
| metric 'my_source.com/api_request_count_total/counter'
| filter metric.route = 'all_endpoints'
| every($__interval)
| group_by [metric.version]
```

This works, but `metric.version` includes patch numbers that I don't want, causing a legend like this: [image: Example Legend]

So I'm trying to leverage `re_replace`:

```
| group_by [re_replace(metric.version, '.*_(..\...?).*', r'\1')]
```

But the new legend looks like this:

[image]

The aggregation itself seems to be working correctly as I'm noticing less entries in the legend overall. But the label itself in the legend is broken

Answer (score 0):

Found this syntax that does the trick:

```
| group_by [metric.version: re_replace(metric.version, "<your regex>", r"\1")]
```